# Python exponential curve fitting

Tags: python, curve, exponential

I have added excel plot from which I get the exponential equation, I am trying to curve fit this in Python.

My fitted equation is not as close to the empirical data i have provided  when i use it to predict the y data,  the prediction gives  f(-25)=  5.30e-11, while the empirical data f(-25) gives = 5.3e-13

How can i improve the code to be predicting close to empirical data, or i have made mistakes in my code??

[python fitted plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BA9Po.png)

![][2]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import scipy.optimize as optimize
import scipy.stats as stats

pd.set_option('precision', 14)

def f(x,A,B):
    return A * np.exp((-B) * (x))

y_data= [2.156e-05,  1.85e-07,  1.02e-10 , 1.268e-11,  5.352e-13]
x=  [-28.8,  -27.4,  -26 , -25.5,  -25]
p, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(f,  x,   y_data,   p0=[10**(-59),4],    maxfev=5000)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, y_data, 'ko', label="Empirical BER")
plt.plot(x, f(x, *p ), 'g-', label="Fitted BER" )
plt.title(" BER  ")
plt.xlabel('Power Rx (dB)')
plt.ylabel('')
plt.legend()
plt.grid()
plt.yscale("log")
plt.show()
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: When I compare the graph and the code, it seems that in the code you are confusing `x` and `y`.

Comment: @mkrieger1, thanks for formatting the question, the problem is that the fitting is not predicting correct y_data set data. I am wondering where i have gone wrong ? fresh eyes might catch my mistake

Comment: @John Coleman , thanks , can you explain further where the confusion is

Comment: I have no idea what it is predicting and what you expected it to predict instead.

Comment: I think the problem is simply that the model function is not suitable at all for this data.

Comment: When adding a constant term to `f` and using less extreme initial values, it kind of works.

Comment: @John Coleman, I have corrected the x , y  data sets, thanks but this mistake was just on posting,

Comment: @stackoverflow, kindly re open the question, I have addressed issues raised , Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you are plotting the data with a log-plot, your view of the data and fit is emphasizing the "tiny" compared to the "small".  Fitting uses the sum of the squares of the misfit to determine the best fit.  A misfit of a few percent of the data with a y-value of ~2e-5 would completely swamp a misfit of a factor of 10 or even 100 for the data with a y-value of 1.e-11.  Your plot is consistent with that.

There are two possible routes to a better fit:

a) if you have uncertainties in the y-values, use those.  It's quite possible that the uncertainty in the data with y~2e-5 is much larger than the uncertainty in the date with y~1.e-11, and scaling by the uncertainty so that the minimization is of the sum-of-squares of `(data-model)/uncertainty` will help fit the low-value data better.  OTOH, if the errors are constant, plotting those uncertainties might show that the fit you have is actually not that bad -- the misfit where y~1.e-11 is only 1.e-10.

b) realize that you are assessing the fit quality by plotting the log of the data, and embrace that observation so that you fit the `log(data)` to `log(model)`. Conveniently for a simple exponential function, the log of that model is linear, so you could do linear regression of the log of your data.

**Bonus round:** recognize that options a) and b) are related.  Since a fit minimizes `Sum[ ((data-model)/uncertainty)**2]`, not providing values for `uncertainty` is effectively saying that the has same uncertainty (=1.0 in fact) for all values of `x` and `y`.  If you fit the log of the model to the log of the data, as with`Sum[ (log(data) - log(model))**2]` is effectively saying that the uncertainty in the `log(data)` is the same for all values of `x` and `y`.

Comment: @M Newville  thanks a lot for the clarification and interpretation the data